# How to override memory access functions (malloc, realloc etc) in libavformat with my own custom functions

Tags: c, ffmpeg, mpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am using libavformat-dev package to get some media file properties like bitrate, duration etc. However, I want to use my custom malloc, calloc, realloc functions in place of the system functions that libavformat uses. Is there a way of registering my custom functions in libavformat?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/08/lets-hook-a-library-function/

Comment: Alk, I think it could have been an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg library uses "av_" prefixed function names for memory management. You can simply overload these functions in your application, so your versions will be used by runtime linker, e.g.:

```c
void *av_malloc(size_t size) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Hijacking FFmpeg malloc(): Requested %zd bytes\n", size);
    return malloc(size);
}
```

Note from the FFmpeg source code:

> If you want to override these functions with your own
> implementations (not recommended) you have to link libav* as
> dynamic libraries and remove -Wl,-Bsymbolic from the linker flags.
> Note that this will cost performance.

References:
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavu__mem.html
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/mem_8c_source.html#l00260